# Invalid expression error 000358 when using in_memory workspace?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, in-memory, error-000358

[Make Feature Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm) with an SQL Selection Expression against a geometry property like length fails when the source feature class is in an [`in_memory` workspace](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/the-in-memory-workspace.htm). An otherwise identical model works just fine when the feature class source is in a regular workspace (file-gdb).

```
ERROR 000358: Invalid expression Shape_Length = 0
Failed to execute (Layer of Zero Length Lines).
```

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1 but don't believe the issue to be version specific.

#### Fail:

[image: Model diagram and relevant tool properties for failure situation]

#### Success:

[image: Model diagram and relevant tool properties for success situation]

Comment: I think we should probably Merge this Q&A with the Duplicate because the underlying cause is identical and your answer will apply to both.

Comment: @PolyGeo that'd be fine by me, providing the question of this one doesn't get lost (been awhile since I was involved in a merge, don't remember how it works).

Answer (score 2):

Answer from Esri Canada tech support:

> The behaviour you are bumping is a known limitation of in memory
> layers. They actually don't have a shape_length field to access. For
> example, if you add the output of the XY to Line tool to your display
> and you then open the attribute table you shouldn't see a shape_length
> field available.
>
> That being said, I believe there is an easy solution.
> In your model if you add a "Add Geometry Attributes" tool in between
> the XY to Line and the Layer of Zero Length  Lines tool and ask that
> Add Geometry Attributes tool to calculate length it will add a LENGTH
> field that you can leverage in the Layer of Zero Length Lines tool.

In my case the simplest change is to just not use in_memory at all as the performance gain is negligible. I was using memory as a shortcut to not adding a Delete step at the end of the model. The information for what is going on though is important and will surely crop up elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah they leave those fields out to help performance.  One thing that you could do is make use of the [arcpy.scracthGDB environment](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//001w00000047000000) instead